# Why was my question about null void error in Ruby closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I asked *[Why is `return a or b` a void value expression error in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935179/why-is-return-a-or-b-a-syntax-error-in-ruby#34935179)*, and it was marked as a duplicate of *[Difference between "or" and || in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)*. However, the duplicate does not answer my question. In fact, the question still stands if I remove all reference to the `||` operator (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34935179/3)).

Why was it closed as a duplicate?

Comment: It was closed by a gold badge holder, so (IIRC) you should be able to '@' comment them on the question and try to get them to explain why they dupe closed it. It could be they misunderstood your question. Or it could be they saw something with your question and the dupe that you missed.

Comment: I  think proper course of actions should have been to update linked duplicate to clarify that `return a or b` is common confusing case. Note that "duplicate" does not mean you asked bad question, just that answer is the same.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But the answer is not the same, compare the accepted answer from both questions.

Comment: The answer to your question makes me want to run screaming from anything Ruby.